# Is there a database for space junk beyond Earth orbit, and is Roadster in it?

Tags: debris, tesla-roadster

After a bit of low drama I've come to accept that Roadster is space junk and agree with [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/24953/12102).

After reading [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/26799/12102) about space junk in orbit around Earth, I'd like to ask if there is a database similar to the one linked there but for space junk beyond Earth's orbit, and if so, is Roadster in it yet?

Comment: Hey! Roadster isn't junk yet! Or at least... I don't think it would be non-functional. That there is still a functioning automobile! Resale price might be a bit hampered by the cost of relocation though...

Answer (score 4):

Check out this [List of lists of artificial objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_artificial_objects) on Wikipedia. It contains a [list of artificial objects in heliocentric orbits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_artificial_objects_in_heliocentric_orbit), **including the Roadster**, a [List of artificial objects leaving the Solar System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_artificial_objects_leaving_the_Solar_System) and a [List of solar System probes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Solar_System_probes).

I however don't know of a list combining all three of those. Also apparently some upper stages are missing in the first list.

Comment: While not an "official list of space junk" (Voyagers are not yet junk) this is a great list, and there's Roadster!

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look at https://www.space-track.org/ This is the database used by the[Stuffin Space](http://stuffin.space/) project. Previously AGI provided a database, but I don't believe this is freely downloadable anymore.

Edit: I contacted space-track.org and they do support other objects:

> Yes, anything that launched is generally available regardless of orbit. You can get this by searching the SatCat table https://www.space-track.org/#catalog for "tesla".
>
> Here is the API link to the roadster from the SatCat table:
>   https://www.space-track.org/basicspacedata/query/class/satcat/NORAD_CAT_ID/43205/format/html/emptyresult/show

Comment: I did indeed misread your question, I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: It happens to me too, in fact just a half-day ago I had to create a new question to make a place to move an answer after I re-read the question ;-)  https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/31655/7982 I think it's fine for you to leave this one here. Thanks!

Comment: Updated answer, having reached out to Space-Track.org

Comment: That's great news, thanks! What I'm looking for is "a database for space junk beyond Earth orbit..." Do you know how to generate the table for all objects *beyond Earth orbit*? The first link shows the entire satcat, the second link only Roadster.

Comment: @uhoh Space-Track may have satcat entries for those objects, but once they are beyond earth orbit like Pioneer 11 it doesn't have TLEs.

Comment: @Revent you are absolutely right, thanks! So while the satcat might (or might not) be considered a minimal cataloguing of space junk beyond Earth orbit, it certainly doesn't tell us much about where to start looking for it. Your point is also covered in answers to [Has a TLE ever been issued for a spacecraft trajectory not bound to Earth orbit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24314/12102)

Comment: @Revent Also, while answers to [Where might astrometric observations of the Roadster spacecraft be catalogued?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/25117/7982) mention the "Distant Artificial Satellites Observation" or [DASO Circulars](https://www.minorplanetcenter.net/iau/DASO/DASO.html), they only catalogue observations that people choose to report.

Comment: BTW there is a 'space-track' tag on this Stack Exchange for asking 'Space Track' related questions - I did them know about this, so hopefully they'll help out with further Q&A. See: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-track

Answer (score 1):

Nasa horizons has a database of objects in the solar system, both natural and man-made.

If you go to https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi and go into the change target body section there is an option to choose from a list of spacecraft. I don't know how complete said list is and there doesn't seem to be an option to filter by whether the spacecraft is active and whether it is in heliocentric orbit.

Comment: Thanks! OK I'm going to check this out against Wikipedia's [list of artificial objects in heliocentric orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_artificial_objects_in_heliocentric_orbit) mentioned [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/26817/12102); perhaps it's more complete than I'd originally though.

Answer (score 1):

The best source is [Jonathan's Deep Space Catalog](https://planet4589.org/space/deepcat/index.html). It include pretty much everything that has left orbit of the Earth. And it does include Elon's Tesla Roadster, among other things.

```
D00993 Elon's Tesla Roadster...  Attached to D00992 Falcon Heavy-001 Stage...
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I've never gone through McDowell's site except in passing, never new this kind of stuff was there. I may ask some questions about it but the problem is that the explanations there are so good it may be hard to find something unexplained ;-)