# Listing objects and space probes beyond Earth orbit in Space Track?

Tags: probe, debris, space-track

Can anyone tell me how to query Space Track to list objects that are beyond Earth orbit. I am thinking of things such as the Voyagers, the Tesla Roadster and Pioneer, as examples?

While there is a Wikipedia page on [space probes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_probe), it would be interesting to see if Space Track can be queried for this information.

Note, there is a [related question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/26810), but this is more focused on using Space Track.